# why does svn commit fail silently on external changelist?

Tags: svn

When committing a changelist of files that are located in an external in your svn checkout, why does the svn commit command fail silently?

Note: I am aware now that you must cd into the root of the external to perform the commit, but why can't svn figure out that you are committing files that are in an external? And at the very least, why isn't there an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that it succeeds silently, committing nothing?

Comment: huh, didn't think of that, though it seems like a commit that commits nothing should be considered a failure..

Comment: It may be considered a failure, I'd say ;-)